# Split the dataset into two subsets in matlab/octave

Tags: matlab, octave

Split the dataset into two subsets, say, "train" and "test", with
the train set containing 80% of the data and the test set containing the remaining 20%.

Splitting means to generate a logical index of length equal to
the number of observations in the dataset, with 1 for a training
sample and 0 for at test sample.

N=length(data.x)

Output: logical arrays called idxTrain and idxTest.

Comment: data has only one column 32000x1

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
% Generate sample data...
data = rand(32000,1);

% Calculate the number of training entries...
train_off = round(numel(data) * 0.8);

% Split data into training and test vectors...
train = data(1:train_off);
test = data(train_off+1:end);
```

But if you really want to rely on logical indexing, you can proceed as follows:

```
% Generate sample data...
data = rand(32000,1);
data_len = numel(data);

% Calculate the number of training entries...
train_count = round(data_len * 0.8);

% Create the logical indexing...
is_training = [true(train_count,1); false(data_len-train_count,1)];

% Split data into training and test vectors...
train = data(is_training);
test = data(~is_training);
```

You can also go for the [randsample function](https://mathworks.com/help/stats/randsample.html) in order to achieve some randomness in your extractions, but this won't grant you an exact number of draws for test and training elements every time you run the script:

```
% Generate sample data...
data = rand(32000,1);

% Generate a random true/false indexing with unequally weighted probabilities...
is_training = logical(randsample([0 1],32000,true,[0.2 0.8]));

% Split data into training and test vectors...
train = data(is_training);
test = data(~is_training);
```

You may avoid this problem by producing a correct number of test and training indices and then shuffling them using a [randperm](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html) based indexing:

```
% Generate sample data...
data = rand(32000,1);
data_len = numel(data);

% Calculate the number of training entries...
train_count = round(data_len * 0.8);

% Create the logical indexing...
is_training = [true(train_count,1); false(data_len-train_count,1)];

% Shuffle the logical indexing...
is_training = is_training(randperm(32000));

% Split data into training and test vectors...
train = data(is_training);
test = data(~is_training);
```

Comment: the data has income in it with just two strings >50k and <=50k with dimensions 32000x1. how the code  would incorporate with it?

Comment: If you write "`with the train set containing 80%`", I suggest you a script for producing a training set containing 80% of the entries. Read my code again, you should be smart enough to understand how to use a different percentage. If things are more complex than this, you should reformulate your question being as specific as possible about what you are trying to do.

Comment: thanks for the code. It did split mt data into 80 and 20 percent, but the income column has to have zero's and one's. Im new to matlab. Its bit overwhelming for me. thanks

Comment: Income? What are you talking abour?